# style in css is not updating in wodpress

Tags: wordpress

i have this code to import the css it's working fine but not updating my css latest update right now

```
// style imports
function themeslug_enqueue_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', plugins_url('/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css', __FILE__), false );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', plugins_url('/assets/mystyle.css', __FILE__), false );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_style' );
add_action('showForm', 'showInterface');
```

**this is my plugin directory**

```
turnvoer-calculator
    assets
       mystyle.css
    turnover-calculator.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your stylesheet **(mystyle.css)** success enqueue but it's not update your latest changes - most of the case is because of cache issue (usually have at least 2 layers of cache in a WP site).

So you need to force your WP site to load the newest version of your stylesheet by adding **time argument** to your **stylesheet's url**. Your case, using this code:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', plugins_url('/assets/mystyle.css?time=', __FILE__).time(), [], false );
```

Please replace it with your code and try again.